# Variable (iUserNum2) does not exist in the current context in PowerOf function in C#

Tags: c#

/* Hello I am a student trying to do some practice programming tasks, but I can't seem to get one of my variables to work in a function, I need the value of the variable to be inputted by the user, but it wants we to declare it inside the PowerOf function rather than the Main function, sorry to be a n00b, but any help would be greatly appreciated. [:*/

```
using System;

namespace ThePowerOf
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            string sUserInput;
            int iUserNum1 = 0;
            int iUserNum2 = 0;
            int iPower = 0;

            Console.WriteLine ("Enter a number");
            sUserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            iUserNum1 = Int16.Parse(sUserInput);

            Console.WriteLine ("Enter a number");
            sUserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            iUserNum2 = Int16.Parse(sUserInput);

            iPower = PowerOf(iUserNum1);

            Console.WriteLine((iUserNum1) + (" To the power of ") + (iUserNum2) + (" = ") + (iPower));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static int PowerOf(int iUserNum1)

        {   

        for (int i = 0; i < iUserNum2; ++i)

        {

        iUserNum1 = (iUserNum1 * iUserNum1);

        }       

        return iUserNum1;   

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You function was declared wrong way, how can you calculate power raised to a number by passing a single parameter (unless one of the value is constant)

Fixed Method Deceleration :

```
    static int PowerOf(int iUserNum1, int iUserNum2)
    {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < iUserNum2; i++)
        {
            result = result*iUserNum1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And do change the way you are invoking the function, invoke it properly with 2 parameters!

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string sUserInput;
        int iUserNum1 = 0;
        int iUserNum2 = 0;
        int iPower = 0;

        Console.Write("Enter a number : ");
        sUserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        iUserNum1 = Int32.Parse(sUserInput); // iUserNum1 is declared as 'int' so Int32.Parse()

        Console.Write("Enter a number to waise power to :");
        sUserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        iUserNum2 = Int32.Parse(sUserInput); // iUserNum2 is declared as 'int' so Int32.Parse()

        iPower = PowerOf(iUserNum1, iUserNum2);

        Console.WriteLine(iUserNum1 + " To the power of " + iUserNum2 + " = " + iPower);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Didn't even think of that. +1 for you.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - thnx! i been through all that year ago! used to do silly mistakes!

Comment: Hello, when I invoke the function with two parameters it ruins the math, if the second parameter is added the maths does not produce the correct answer, that is why I only want to include iUserNum1. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Move your declaration of `iUserNum2` into the class level:

```
class MainClass
{
    int iUserNum2 = 0; // PUT IT HERE
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
```

Variables declared in methods aren't shared. Variables declare within a class are shared (provided they are non-static and used in non-static methods.. but that's for you to learn later).

Comment: Hello, I declared the variable in the MainClass, but I now get this message (An object reference is required to access non static member 'ThePowerOf.MainClass.iUserNum2')